# Which totally complex number field's embeddings correspond to geometric rotations/reflections in an argand diagram?

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers, algebraic-number-theory

For which totally complex number fields $K$ with embeddings $\{ \sigma_1, \dots, \sigma_m\}$ do we have the equality:

$$
|\sigma_1(x)| = |\sigma_2(x)| = \dots = |\sigma_m(x)|,
$$

for all $x \in K$ where $|\cdot|$ corresponds to the complex absolute value $|x| = (x\bar{x})^{1/2}$? In other words, which number fields have embeddings that do not affect the distance of a coordinate on an argand diagram?

Comment: What do the units have to be? They would also have to have absolute value 1.

Comment: @TCiur be that as it may, how does it help answer my question?

Comment: @TCiur I believe the quadratic extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ where $d$ is a squarefree negative integer satisfies the condition too.

Comment: Your condition requires that all archimedean places of K coincide, but this does not occur. The only possibility is when there is only 1 archimedean place, and this happens when we have a pair of complex embeddings, I.E an imaginary quadratic field

Comment: I might be showing my ignorance here, but don't they all satisfy that condition?

Comment: There are $r + c$ Archimedean places for a number field with $r$ real embeddings and $c$ pairs of complex embeddings, They each correspond to $|\sigma(x)|$ for real embeddings or $|\sigma(x)\cdot \bar{\sigma(x)}|$ for complex embeddings. It should be known that these are inequivalent but I can't find a proof anywhere online. My answer can be considered a half proof for the complex case.

Comment: Inequivalence is a stronger condition. It is true that letting $x$ vary, $|\sigma(x)| \neq |\sigma'(x)|^k$ for any $\sigma , \sigma'$ and positive integer $k$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your condition, we must have that every galois action acts via multiplication by some complex unit:

$|x| = |\sigma(x)| \implies \sigma(x) = u \cdot x$ for some complex unit $u$.

Assume $\sigma(x) = u \cdot x$, then $\sigma(x+1) = u\cdot x + 1 = w\cdot x + w$ for some other unit $w$. This would imply that $|x+1| = |u\cdot x + 1|$. This is absurd unless $u\cdot x = \bar{x}$ or $x$. Hence the galois group must consist only of the identity and the complex conjugate (only imaginary quadratic fields fit the condition).

Comment: The embeddings on cyclotomic fields don't affect the absolute value of a cyclotomic number either, unless I am mistaken, as they correspond to shifts in the argument of the number in the complex plane.

Comment: In any cyclotomic field, non-complex-conjugate galois actions on $\zeta + \zeta^{-1}$ will change the absolute value (think geometrically).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - you're absolutely correct. Thanks for the response!